# How do you finely grind coriander seeds?

Tags: spices, coriander

Whenever I grind coriander seeds the outside seems to separate like a husk and doesn't grind well.

I use a pestel and mortar.

Is there a trick to getting finely ground coriander?

Comment: Do you have a coffee grinder?

Comment: @Jolenealaska : I've had mine for years.  I've thought about getting one with a metal work area, (less issues with flavorings lingering), or a Krups Type 223 (so I can make my own Mr. Fusion), but for now, my under-$20 blade grinder works just fine.  (and I think I've had it 10+ years)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend a dedicated, rotary style coffee grinder for home spice grinding. Whole spices last longer, usually taste better, and are often less expensive than pre-ground. In many food cultures, whole spices are often toasted whole, then ground. It makes a big difference for not a lot of effort.

I picked up a rotary style [coffee grinder](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004SPEU) for $3 at a thrift store.

[image: 1]

I use it to grind all kinds of spices. It never needs to be washed. If it starts to taste like last weeks spices, I just grind up some rice and shake it out. It works great, I've ground spices in the same grinder for 5 years.

Comment: I used to use a coffee grinder for this, but one of the better purchases I have made is a dedicated spice grinder.  The blades are a bit lower, so it can grind things more finely, and the cup is detachable from the base so that it can be washed along with the lid.  I used to do the "grind rice to clean it out" trick, which worked fine, but being able to wash it well and completely get last meal's cumin and chile out of it is wonderful.