# How do I add spice after cooking gravy?

Tags: spices, gravy

I have made chicken gravy. It tastes good but I think adding a little more spice to my gravy will be fine. Can anyone say how to add more spice to it after cooking?

Comment: WHICH spices were you planning to add?

Answer (score 2):

Carefully! You can always add more, but you can't really remove spices once they are added.

If your spices are ground, you can just add them to the gravy and stir them in. Salt, you can add any time.

If your spices are whole, you can simmer them for a while in the gravy and them remove them. You can also toast them in a separate dry pan, grind them (see [here](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/57712/how-do-you-finely-grind-coriander-seeds/57714#57714)), and then add them to your gravy. Again, *carefully!*

Answer (score 1):

Simply adding spices later doesn't always work. If your spices were supposed to be sautéed in the recipe then you have to sauté them first and then add them or you will get raw spice flavour. Look at the recipe and find out how your spices were supposed to go in. If you are sautéing separately then you have to be careful because spices can burn really quickly if sautéed by themselves. Once you have recreated the spice flavour just mix it in and cook to finish.

Answer (score 0):

If your gonna add spices after the fact put the gravy back in the pot heat it up add spices and if it gets to thick add more water. Most spices need to "bloom" so to speak in liquid to get to full potency so add some spices cook for about 5 mins then taste ...